# Identifying the numbers of degree $n$ covering spaces of $X$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $X$ be a path-connected, locally path-connected and semilocally simply-connected space. Can we find a correspondence between degree $n$ covering spaces of $X$ and group homomorphism $\pi_1(X)\rightarrow S_n$? ($S_n$ is the permutation group)

Comment: From the classification of covering spaces of such a space, we know they are in correspondence with the subgroups of the fundamental group. Can you relate the index of the subgroup with some useful parameter of the covering?

Comment: Don't the subgroups of index n correspond to connected coverings only?

Comment: Connected $n$ covering spaces are in correspondence with the orbits of all index $n$ subgroup acted by conjugation. I cannot find an easy way to identify these orbits.